# How to change the version 1.21.x of dpkg tool of Ubuntu22.04 to the version 1.19.x of dpkg tool of Ubuntu20.04?

Tags: dpkg

I met a problem when making .deb in Ubuntu22.04, because the target environment does not support .deb made by dpkg version of 1.21.x. So I need to install dpkg tool with version 1.19.x just the same as that of Ubuntu20.04 in Ubuntu22.04. Could someone kindly provide an installation tutorial? Thanks very much!

I used "apt purge dpkg" to remove dpkg , but it failed because some software stopped the unintallation process.

Comment: Ah, no that's not going to be possible without some serious surgery of the internals. What is the actual error message you're getting? Deb packages built with any recent version should install fine on any other recent version ***provided*** dependencies are met. Your problem is unlikely to be due to dpkg unless this package depends on dpkg itself.

Comment: I am installing .deb into a docker. The docker environment does not support 1.21.x version of dpkg, but supports 1.19.x version of dpkg. I've tested this. So I come here for help.

Comment: What's the actual error you are getting?

Comment: I am trying to install some apps into a container and before installation, the apps should be packaged into .ova. Here comes the problem, which has been confirmed, the dpkg tool with version of 1.21.x of Ubuntu22.04 uses a different packaging strategy. So, the .ova package made in Ubuntu22.04 couldnot be identified by my current container. But the .ova package made in Ubuntu20.04 could be identified by my current container. So, I want to replace the dpkg tool of Ubuntu22.04 with the dpkg tool of version 1.19.x. But, I searched the Internet and found no tutorial. Then, I come here for help.